# several eps to ps

Tags: pdf, postscript

I have a bunch of eps vector images (btw... they are generated from dxf), and want to stack them on a single ps so I can print them on a single sheet. The eps files share the same dimensions but have slightly different content.

I'm looking for or want to write a script that I can give parameters like x,y offsets, and it'll place the eps's on a grid.

I was thinking using LaTeX, but I guess it is a bit overkill.